# theoretical time complexity of python libraries that use LAPACK routines

Tags: python, numpy, time-complexity, linear-algebra

I'm using some of the functions that numpy.linalg provide such as numpy.linalg.svd, scipy.linalg.qr, scipy.linalg.lstsq and more. The API for these function say that they use some LAPACK routines, for example numpy.linalg.svd uses LAPACK routine _gesdd. my problem is that I need the theoretical time complexity of those function and I could find any information of this.

Where I can find this information?

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is going through research article references from [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node53.html). Although there is a chance someone who knows the actual numbers sees this post. A nice comparison of experimental times can be found [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Edemmel/cs267/lecture12/lecture13a.html), but this is not quite what you were looking for.